# DB2 is_autoincrement and primary key issue

Tags: sql, database, insert, db2, auto-increment

Good day,

I have a table, which some columns, and `BELTID` set to primary key, and `IS_AUTOINCREMENT` set to `YES`.

I wish to insert a row of data inside this data without key in the BELTID, I am expect the BELDID will auto generate.

The query is as follow:

```
INSERT INTO mySchema.TABLE1(TYPE, ORIGINALBATCHID, MANUAL) 
VALUES ('TEST',  124,  1);
```

I get this error:

> SQLSTATE: 23505. A violation of the constraint imposed by a unique index or a unique constraint occurred.

Then I change my query to:

```
INSERT INTO mySchema.TABLE1(BELTID, TYPE, ORIGINALBATCHID, MANUAL) 
VALUES (123, 'TEST',  124,  1);
```

And I am getting another error:

> SQLSTATE: 428C9 A ROWID column cannot be specified as the target column of an INSERT or UPDATE.

Kindly advise on what mistake I make.

Comment: Please show is the complete table definition. What DB2 version and platform?

Comment: What are the triggers on that table?